# Second order linear differential equation reduction of order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation is to be solved using method of reduction of order:
$$ y''-4ty' +(4t^2 -2)y=0$$
$$ y_1 (t)=e^{t^{2}} $$ 
Using the method of reduction of order I've arrived to this part,
$$y_2 (t)=v(t) y_1 (t)$$
$$y_2'(t)=e^{t^{2}} (2t v(t)+v'(t)) $$
$$y_2''(t)=e^{t^{2}} ((4t^2 +2)v(t)+4tv'(t)+ v''(t)) $$
plugging the values in original equation
$$ e^{t^{2}} v''(t) =0$$
$$ v''(t)=0$$
$$ v(t) = C_1 + C_2t$$

Comment: Is the problem written correctly? Like is there a $y$ on those last terms?

Comment: i have made some edits, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Moo yes, i have changed it

Comment: Is the original problem written correctly?

Comment: @Moo I guess there should be a y on the last term otherwise it won't be possible to solve this problem

Comment: That is correct - it is very nasty - can you check where the error is?

Comment: @Moo I've corrected the problem, I think there was some printing mistake on the question itself

Comment: Well, now we get $e^{t^2} v''(t) = 0$, which looks much better!

Comment: Well $e^{t^2}\neq0$ no.?

Comment: @MyGlasses: No! The Reduction of Order step produces what I show. In the next step, of course that is what you do.

Comment: Maybe $v''=0$ so $v=at+b$ shows another solution?

Comment: That is the solution. Of course, he has to take $y_2(t) = v e^{t^2}$.

Comment: @Moo you are right, i have made mistakes earlier, thanks for all the help

Comment: Don't forget that you want $y_2(t) = v(t) ~ e^{t^2}$

Comment: of course mate!!